# Why does WSL2 Ubuntu-20.04 not show ubuntu in the kernel name

Tags: version

I use `Windows Terminal Version: 1.12.10982.0` to launch an Ubuntu-20.04 shell which gives the following output.

```bsh
$ uname -r
5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
$ uname -a
Linux NeilCrow 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please can someone explain to me why the output doesn't show that ubuntu is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not running a kernel provided by Ubuntu/Canonical, but the [WSL2 Linux kernel provided by Microsoft.](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel).

The `uname` output reflects this.

To get information about what distro you are using, check `/etc/issue` or `lsb_release -a`.